# Running a Near blockchain locally

Tags: blockchain, nearprotocol

I am trying to setup a local NEAR blockchain network on couple of machines, which shouldn't fetch any data from outside network. I am following these docs:
https://docs.near.org/pt-BR/docs/develop/node/validator/compile-and-run-a-node/
But after i start up the process, i see these logs. Does it mean it is synchronysing with external blockchain network ?

`2022-12-08T16:59:00.302694Z  INFO near_chain::doomslug: ready to produce block @ 1004, has enough approvals for 31.975µs, has enough chunks`

I tried removing the boot nodes from the config.json as well, but didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can also run a localized version of the network on your machine by using [kurtosis](https://docs.near.org/develop/testing/kurtosis-localnet#launching-cluster). The steps for running are:

1. Launch Docker
2. `curl -o ~/launch-local-near-cluster.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kurtosis-tech/near-package/master/launch-local-near-cluster.sh -L`
3. `chmod u+x ~/launch-local-near-cluster.sh`
4. `~/launch-local-near-cluster.sh`

---

EDIT: You can also run your own cluster of nodes on machines managed by yourself by following the [instructions here](https://github.com/near/nearcore/blob/master/docs/practices/workflows/localnet_on_many_machines.md).